# Ruby--How to get input from server without error? (socket.gets.chomp throwing error)

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, client, chomp

I'm running a server/client program, I keep getting an error I don't understand:

```
FishClientRun.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Shizuo:FISHGAME2 macowner$
```

However, the code *runs once*.  It actually receives the cards and stores them just fine.  When the client comes loops back around and *hangs* on the get statement `incoming = client.socket.gets.chomp`.  It doesn't like the `.chomp.`  If I take of the `.chomp`, it hangs like it is supposed to without throwing an error, but then I get the newline character and get bad input for `client.input_decision(incoming)`.

My client:

```
client = ClientClass.new('localhost', 2012)

while true
    puts "IN WHILE TRUE!!!"
    incoming = ""
    incoming = client.socket.gets.chomp
    puts "INPUT RECEIVED:::::::: #{incoming}"

    client.input_decision(incoming)
end
```

Here's the server.  I think this part is okay:

```
server = SocketServerClass.new(2012, number_of_players)

number_of_players.times do 
    server.accept_client(server.fish_game)
end
puts "Clients accepted"

server.update_client_cards(server.fish_game)
puts "client cards sent to server"

while true
sleep(10)
break
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` will return `nil` if it encounters an end of file. Presumably, you want to terminate at that point.

Comment: Okay, so that's why it always exits at about 10 seconds, because that's when I get to the EOF and the client malfunctions.  Thank you!